# ASP.NET Webmatrix using .aspx instead of Razor

Tags: asp.net, database, webmatrix

I would like to know if there is a tutorial that teaches how to build your pages in Webmatrix but **using .aspx and not razor**.

All the tutorials I've found so far only teaches Razor syntax and I can't use that because my webhosting doesn't support .cshtml.

I would like to connect to a database and performs SQL Querys, so a tutorial or article that shows how to do that will work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. ASP.NET Web Pages (what you're using in WebMatrix) ONLY uses Razor.

I seriously doubt your host doesn't support CSHTML files. If they support .NET 4.0, then they support CSHTML files. Nothing else needs to be installed on their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider doesn't have to support .cshtml pages.  Unlike Web Forms, which use a .aspx extension on the URL, and must be mapped in the IIS configuration, Web Pages uses Routing and by default drops the suffix, so no configuration is needed by the hosting provider.

When you publish a Web pages site, it copies the necessary razor rendering files to the bin directory.

It's not possible to have a Web Pages site without Razor.

Comment: Thank you both for your response and the clarification. I guess I got confused a bit. My hosting provider says they do support .asp net. But the razor pages I upload remain blank when I try to load them. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreaAcosta - You can't just upload the razor pages.  You have to publish the site using the publish function.  By the way, you "thank" people by upvoting their answers, or marking them as the answer to your question.